# Wordpress get the first attached image on the post

Tags: php, wordpress

Today I've been trying to display the most popular post in wordpress using the following code:

http://pastebin.com/TjJTiiTZ

It works great however it's not allowing me to grab the first attached image on the post. I need to do it that way in order to get the image from any of the several custom fields holding the images.

I tried to use the following code (which actually works on another customization) to get the first attached image on the post but I have not been able to make it work.

```
$p = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order ID',
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
);

$thumb = get_posts($p);
    if ($thumb) {
    $imgsrc = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb[0]->ID, 'thumbnail');
    $img = $imgsrc[0];
    }
```

Is there any way in which this can be accomplish??

Comment: Try changing `$attachments[0]->ID` to `$thumb[0]->ID`

Comment: What is the content of `$thumb` if you debug it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to get posts first attachment image:

```
$catposts = get_posts('category='.$category_id."&order=DESC&numberposts=".$NUMBEROFPOSTS);
function catch_that_image($_catposts)
{
$first_img = '';
ob_start();
ob_end_clean();
$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $_catposts->post_content, $matches);
$first_img = $matches[1][0];
return $first_img;
}

$j=0;
foreach ($catposts as $item) :
    $get_contents = $item->post_content;
    $regex_pattern = "/<a href=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>/";
        $output = preg_match_all($regex_pattern,$item->post_content, $matches);
    echo '<img src="'.catch_that_image($catposts[$j]).'" alt="" border="0px" />';
    $j++;
endforeach;
```

where $category_id is specific category id . suppose if you have a category id = 26 then all 26 category posts display in foreach loop.

on that related posts first image display which you enter in posts.

Thank you.

Comment: It works great, however what I'm trying to accomplish is to get the post from any field on the post meta. Your code will only search for any image inserted in the post content. I need to search any image that is attached to the post (either in the description or on the featured image, custom fields, etc..)